# Solving an ordinary differential equation on a fixed grid (preferably in python)

Tags: python, math, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I have a differential equation of the form

`dy(x)/dx = f(y,x)`

that I would like to solve for `y`.

I have an array `xs` containing all of the values of `x` for which I need `ys`.

For only those values of `x`, I can evaluate `f(y,x)` for any `y`.

How can I solve for `ys`, preferably in python?

### MWE

```
import numpy as np

# these are the only x values that are legal
xs = np.array([0.15, 0.383, 0.99, 1.0001])

# some made up function --- I don't actually have an analytic form like this
def f(y, x):
    if not np.any(np.isclose(x, xs)):
        return np.nan
    return np.sin(y + x**2) 

# now I want to know which array of ys satisfies dy(x)/dx = f(y,x)
```

Comment: Could you comment on the analytical form?

Comment: I have vectors of quantities. The real equation looks something like `f(y,x) = 4pi c z1 x**2 * integral_x^1 z2/x**2 y dx - z3` where `c` is a constant and `z1,z2,z3` are vectors. The integral has to be performed numerically.

Comment: Is y a vector as well?

Comment: y itself is not a vector, but the solution `ys` that I seek is a vector

Comment: Ok, from what I gather, the ODE is scalar, but has vector arguments?  I'm using vector distinctly from array in this case, so the numerical solution is an ARRAY.

Comment: I think you can't solve an equation with this condition "if not np.any(np.isclose(x, xs)): return np.nan" because your function is not continuous.

Comment: With the integral in the equation, your problem is no longer an ODE. However, you can transform it into an ODE boundary value problem by defining the integral as additional function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use something simple like Forward Euler...

Numerical solutions will rely on approximate solutions at previous times.  So if you want a solution at `t = 1` it is likely you will need the approximate solution at `t<1`.

My advice is to figure out what step size will allow you to hit the times you need, and then find the approximate solution on an interval containing those times.

```
import numpy as np

#from your example, smallest step size required to hit all would be 0.0001.

a = 0 #start point
b = 1.5 #possible end point
h = 0.0001
N = float(b-a)/h

y = np.zeros(n)
t = np.linspace(a,b,n)
y[0] = 0.1 #initial condition here

for i in range(1,n):
   y[i] = y[i-1] + h*f(t[i-1],y[i-1])
```

Alternatively, you could use an adaptive step method (which I am not prepared to explain right now) to take larger steps between the times you need.

Or, you could find an approximate solution over an interval using a coarser mesh and interpolate the solution.

Any of these should work.

Comment: Hi, based on this answer I am not sure if I was exactly clear. Based on your use of linspace, it seems to me like you are trying to introduce the values of `x` (or in your example, `t`) for which this calculation should be performed. But actually these values are already predefined. Or have I misunderstood your solution?

Comment: That is right, the linspace will tell us where the approximate solution is to be computed.  You can't just jump to a point in time far from your initial condition and compute the answer.

Comment: I am a bit confused by this. In my example, f(y,x) will return NAN for values of x that are not in the array of xs. So won't y[i] be NAN for almost every quantity?

Comment: If your function returns NAN if the current time is not close to a time you want (as per your example) you are in a little bit of trouble.  If you want to know the solution at t=10, for instance, you need the approximate solution in a neighborhood of t = 10.  If you are still confused, let me know and I will reword my answer.

Comment: The use of `t` is confusing me I think. What is `t`? Is it a count of how many iterations have passed? Or is it my `x`?

Comment: t is time.  The independent argument.  I could have easily used x.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should first solve ODE on a regular grid, and then interpolate solution on your fixed grid. The approximate code for your problem

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy import interpolate

xs = np.array([0.15, 0.383, 0.99, 1.0001])

# dy/dx = f(x,y)
def dy_dx(y, x):
    return np.sin(y + x ** 2)

y0 = 0.0 # init condition
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)# here you can control an accuracy
sol = odeint(dy_dx, y0, x)
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, np.ravel(sol))
ys = f(xs)
```

But dy_dx(y, x) should always return something reasonable (not np.none).
Here is the drawing for this case
[image]

Comment: The problem is that I can't call dy_dx for arbitrary values of x. (I guess I could interpolate, but that's it.)

Comment: dy(x)/dx = f(y,x) is a Cauchy problem and f(y,x) should be continous for the correct solution. Interpolation may resolve it (theoretically). In other case you can't solve it with popular numerical methods (like Runge-Kutta)